# Mysql join query, getting list of records and joining votes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am running a join on two tables, but I am having some trouble.

Tables of interest: 'photo', 'vote', 'week'

I am trying to run a query that pulls up a list of photos, included with it, the total amount of votes for the "week" that is active.

The 'vote' table consists of the following foreign keys: photo_id,week_id,user_id.  This allows me to figure out which "week" the vote was placed in.  Also, think of week as an entity not a timeframe..  its just a record in the "week" table.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `weekly_votes` 
FROM (`photo`) 
JOIN `vote` ON `vote`.`photo_id` = `photo`.`id` 
WHERE `vote`.`week_id` = '6' 
GROUP BY `photo`.`id`
```

The problem is this will pull up a list of photos that have votes in the votes table for the specified week, but NO photos are returned if no votes have been given that week.

Basically the:

```
 WHERE `vote`.`week_id` = '6'
```

needs to only apply to stuff in the join statement, and not prevent it from limiting photos returned.  I know at the very least I need to use some sort of OUTER join, but I think the WHERE clause is still going to prevent it from working.

I hope my question makes sense...

Answer (score 3):

You need an outer join. Because you only want to apply your where condition on the outer join, you need to mention the week_id in the join condition.

```
LEFT JOIN `vote` ON `vote`.`photo_id` = `photo`.`id` AND `vote`.`week_id` = '6'
```